# Decorated async method returns None

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-decorators, aiohttp

I have the following class Yodel that fetches data from oficial Yodel API.
To make it faster I am using aiohttp and asyncio but I want to make it seems sync when the user instanciate the object and call its methods. To accomplish that I created a decorator to make it possible to call `tracking` as a synchronous method.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

class Yodel:
    API_BASE_URL = "api.yodel.co.uk"

    CLIENT_ID = "..."
    CLIENT_SECRET = "..."

    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.auth())

    async def auth(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        url = f"https://{Yodel.API_BASE_URL}/tracking/v1.0/oauth2/token"

        payload = f"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={Yodel.CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={Yodel.CLIENT_SECRET}&scope=tracking"
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }

        response = await self.session.request("POST", url=url, data=payload, headers=headers)

        response = await response.json()

        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(
            headers = {
                "Accept": "*/*",
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {response['access_token']}",
                "x-ibm-client-id": Yodel.CLIENT_ID,
            }
        )

    async def fetch_data(self, url, **kwargs):
        response = await self.session.request("GET", url=url, **kwargs)
        response = await response.json()

        return response
    
    def async_loop(f):
        def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.loop.run_until_complete(f(self, *args, **kwargs))
        return decorated

    @async_loop
    async def tracking(self, trackingIds: list, **kwargs):
        tasks = []

        for trackingId in trackingIds:
            endpoint = f"/tracking/v1.0/parcel-tracking/{trackingId}"
            url = f"https://{Yodel.API_BASE_URL}{endpoint}"
            tasks.append(self.fetch_data(url, **kwargs))
        
        trackings = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

        # I see trackings as json when inspecting variables, however...
        return trackings # Returns None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    yodel = Yodel()
    trackings = yodel.tracking([
        "JJD0002247772000106",
        "JJD0002247772000107",
        "JJD0002247772000108"
    ])
```

Returns

```
None
```

Comment: You have to use `await` to call an async function and get the result.

Comment: `decorated` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it always returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh it was only missing

```py
def async_loop(f):
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = self.loop.run_until_complete(f(self, *args, **kwargs))
        return response
    return decorated
```